# How to use ASP.NET Membership with Active Directory for a company

Tags: .net, asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-membership

I am new to the world of ASP.NET Web Forms and I was a Java developer for 3 years and I have a good knowledge of C# but I just used it for developing simple console applications. 
Now, I am having a project in ASP.NET and the first thing I am thinking to do is the administrative tasks like adding users and managing users roles. For this part, I am having two options either to use the forms authentication or to use the active directory. I am gonna use the active directory with the ASP.NET Membership but now I am facing some problems.

I tried to follow the procedures written on the following [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2009/04/23/create-a-minimal-asp-net-membership-website-that-will-come-in-useful-in-another-post.aspx).

But I failed to get them right from the first step which is creating a new website because as you see, the author specified the web location as HTTP and then he specified the located folder as `https://localhost/`.
when I did this it gave me an error message about the inability to connect to the IIS, I don't know what the reason
so I made the location to my file system.
Then for the security, I chose the local Area Network for security because the project that I am developing is for a company so I need to use the windows credentials. 
But at the end, I failed on configuring the membership for the rest of users in the company and I do know what the reason behind that.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a look to these two links :

[How To: Use Forms Authentication with Active Directory in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Active Directory Authentication from ASP .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) out.  You should always include an answer in your answer =)

Comment: The appropriate response, in that case, would be a comment (and a downvote if you feel it's a really bad question), not an answer.  Not trying to hassle you, just helping to make sure the site is used properly.